# Kotlin parse `MMYYYY` into YearMonth

Tags: kotlin, datetime, parsing

I want to parse a `MMYYYY` field to `YearMonth` in kotlin.

Example tried :

```
import java.time.YearMonth
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder

val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("MMYYYY")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)

println(YearMonth.parse("011970", formatter))
```

it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect, it uses the symbol for week based year (`Y`) instead of year (`u`) or maybe year of era (`y`).

Read more about the symbols in the [JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), some of them relevant here are:

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G | era | text | AD; Anno Domini; A |
| u | year | year | 2004; 04 |
| y | year-of-era | year | 2004; 04 |
| … | … | … | … |
| M/L | month-of-year | number/text | 7; 07; Jul; July; J |
| … | … | … | … |
| Y | week-based-year | year | 1996; 96 |

I'd recommend you switch to year:

```kotlin
import java.util.Locale
import java.time.YearMonth
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder

val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("MMuuuu")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)

fun main() {
    println(YearMonth.parse("011970", formatter))
}
```

This code prints `1970-01`

Iif you are sure you will exclusively receive numerical `String`s, you *can* also use a less complex `DateTimeFormatter` by leaving the check for case sensitivity:

```kotlin
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMuuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)
```